# Executing ANT from PHP

Tags: php, ant, exec

I have an HTML form which I am submitting to a PHP script. I am using PHP to write an XML file based on the form input, and then I would like to have PHP execute an ANT buildfile that will use the XML as input for an XSLT task. All of this is part of a much larger application, none of which is exposed beyond our LAN, so security is not a huge concern of mine. My problem is that I cannot get the PHP exec task to start ANT. I have tried seemingly every combination of executing a BAT that calls ANT, using the full path to the ANT binary, calling ANT with java, etc. All roads lead to:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

I am running PHP 5.3 on Windows Server 2008 running IIS7. The PHP is located in inetpub/wwwroot/etc. Ant is installed in C:\Program Files. I personally don't believe it's a permissions issue, but I could be wrong. I have scoured the web in search of the answer, but I have only found the question unanswered or suggestions similar to those mentioned below.

I am currently attempting to install phing, and will consider another server-side scripting language to accomplish the same job (I am just way more comfortable in PHP). But if anyone knows of the issue and how I can work around it that would be awesome.

Cheers!

Comment: Launching a JVM for each HTTP request is very efficient. Not a criticism, just a proposed reason for why others aren't doing this.

Comment: This is a document publishing process which will be run a few times a day at most by one or two individuals in the company. Albeit painfully, I needed to interrupt my application for some manual intervention. The form is essentially an index, with potentially hundreds of entrys that have to be gone through. Antform is another option I considered, as I am already using it, but I wasn't sure what might happen if I suspended the process for an indeterminable period of time, perhaps days. And in my expereience, event-handled processes such as watched directories on Windows is unreliable at best.

Comment: Understood, but launching a VM every time someone pushes a button via a browser could quickly overwhelm the server. That was my point about efficiency and why you have not found prior art in this space.